# Automatically extract qBittorrent downloads

Tags: batch-file, winrar, qbittorrent

I want to automatically extract torrents downloaded with qBittorrent into the same directory.
I have a bat F:\extrator.bat that contains.

```
    @ECHO off
    timeout /t 10 /nobreak
    set arg1=%1
    set arg2=%2
    shift
    shift
    "C:\Program Files\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe" x "%arg1%" "%arg2%"
```

I call this from qBittorrent on download completion with

"F:\extractor.bat" "%F*.rar" "%F"

The qBittorrent log shows the args passed as 
arg1 = F:\Torrent\Finished\downloadname*.rar
arg2 = F:\Torrent\Finished\downloadname

However Winrar reports an error stating that 
C:\Windows\System32\"F:\Torrent\Finished\downloadname*.rar" could not be found.

WinRar seems to add C:\Windows\System32\ to the beginning of arg1.

Anyone have any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Change `set arg1=%1` to `set "arg1=%~1"` and see what happens

Comment: That now pops up a window that says No Files to extract.  My winrar log shows the following.  _--------  28/08/2017 20:41:57, Archive F:\Torrent\Finished\The.Housing.Enforcers.S04E07.720p.HDTV.x264-BARGE\the.housing.enforcers.s04e07.720p.hdtv.x264-barge.rar
28/08/2017 20:41:57   No files to extract_  The files are in the stated location and can be unrared manually with winrar.

Comment: Your winrar command line assumes that there is the file/directory `The.Housing.Enforcers.S04E07.720p.HDTV.x‌​264-BARGE` contained in the archive `F:\Torrent\Finished\The.Housing.Enforcers.S04E07.720p.HDTV.x‌​264-BARGE\the.housin‌​g.enforcers.s04e07.7‌​20p.hdtv.x264-barge.‌​rar`.  Is that so? I guess not. Probably you should omit `"%arg2%"` completely.

Answer (score 1):

Got it to work.
qBittorrent command was `F:\Extractor.bat %F\*.rar %F`

extractor.bat placed in root of F

Contains following script:-

```
timeout /t 10 /nobreak
set "arg1=%~1"
echo "%arg1%"
set "arg2=%2"
shift
shift
"C:\Program Files\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe" x "%arg1%" "%arg2%"
```

This successfully extracts the archive into the same directory.

Comment: This worked for me, but adapted it to use peazip instead and to extract in the parent folder, like this:
timeout /t 10 /nobreak
set "arg1=%~1"
echo "%arg1%"
set "arg2=%2"
shift
shift
"C:\Program Files\PeaZip\peazip.exe" -ext2simple "%arg1%" "%arg2%\..\"

Answer (score 1):

Based on previous answers, I distilled and customized the following command:

```
"C:\Program Files\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe" x -ibck -inul -o+ %F\*.rar %F
```

- `-ibck` will run WinRar in the background
- `-inul` will ignore any potential errors that will be thrown. E.g. "No rar file was found"
- `-o+` will override all files that already exists; `-o-` will skip these.

More info about the command line syntax and switches used by WinRar can be found here:

https://www.winrar-france.fr/winrar_instructions_for_use/source/html/HELPCommandLineSyntax.htm